# ggplot2: obter paleta de cores usada no scale_color

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sabem se é possível obter a paleta de cores usada no scale_color_*? Gostaria de obter as cores específicas (hex color codes) usadas com o pacote `paletteer` em cada caso para depois usa-la em outras aplicações (por exemplo, fazendo join desse desses dados com outros). O que tentei foi o seguinte:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(paletteer)

dados <- data.frame(x = sample(seq(0,100), 100, replace = T),
                    y = sample(seq(0,10), 100, replace = T),
                    valor = sample(seq(-10,10), 100, replace = T))

plot.1 <- dados %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = valor))+
  geom_point()+
  paletteer::scale_color_paletteer_c("ggthemes::Classic Red-White-Green") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Depois de criar o objetio plot.1, tentei verificar se o ggplot2 guardava as cores nos dados com `plot.1$data`, mas isso não acontece. Depois tentei verificar no `mapping` com `plot.1$mapping$colour`, que retorna o seguinte resultado:

```
<quosure>
expr: ^cor
env:  000002299B6E1FD0
```

Não sei se é possível extrair os hex codes daí. No final, eu gostaria de ter um conjunto com as colunas x, y, valor e hex, este último obtido com as cores do gráfico acima gerado.

Desde já, obrigado aos que puderem ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que encontrei você pode usar `ggplot_build` pra montar as informações do gráfico e extrair a cor dos dados.
Outra opção é usar as funções do paletteer para conseguir as cores.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(paletteer)

dados <- data.frame(x = sample(seq(0,100), 100, replace = T),
                    y = sample(seq(0,10), 100, replace = T),
                    valor = sample(seq(-10,10), 100, replace = T))

plot.1 <- dados %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = valor))+
  geom_point()+
  paletteer::scale_color_paletteer_c("ggthemes::Classic Red-White-Green") +
  theme_minimal()


plot_build <- ggplot_build(plot.1)

unique(plot_build$data[[1]]$colour)
#>  [1] "#A81526" "#FFFEFE" "#CC312B" "#FFD9D1" "#5C9F5D" "#DB4E3E" "#C02829"
#>  [8] "#428F49" "#FCB4A5" "#B41F27" "#1B6D32" "#F48F7B" "#E86853" "#97C394"
#> [15] "#9C0824" "#74AF72" "#B9D7B7" "#DCEBDA" "#297839" "#09622A" "#368341"

paletteer::paletteer_c("ggthemes::Classic Red-White-Green", 21)
#> <colors>
#> #9C0824FF #A81526FF #B41F27FF #C02829FF #CC312BFF #DA4E3FFF #E86753FF #F48E7BFF #FCB4A5FF #FFD9D1FF #FFFFFFFF #DCEBDBFF #B9D7B7FF #97C394FF #74AF72FF #5C9F5DFF #428F49FF #368341FF #297839FF #1B6D31FF #09622AFF
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: perfeito, Jorge, a função 'ggplot_build()' era exatamente o que eu estava procurando e não encontrei. Super valeu!